# Transalte Assembly(Solidity)

Tags: solidity, remix, assembly, string, uint256

I want translate code to assembly, but i don't understand , how i can get data from string ( or bytes)
Example String: 123 --> uint 123

```
for (uint256 i = 0; i < bytes(_str).length; i++) 
    {
        if ((uint8(bytes(_str)[i]) - 48) < 0 || (uint8(bytes(_str)[i]) - 48) > 9) 
        {
            return (0, false);
        }
        res = res + (uint8(bytes(_str)[i]) - 48) * (10**(_str.length - i - 1));
    }
```

My try:

```
bytes memory stringNumber = bytes(_str);
    assembly
    {
        
        function power(level,num) -> result
        {
            let i:=0x1
            result := num
            if gt(level,0)
            {
                for {} lt(i,level) {}
                {
                    result := mul(result,num)
                    i:=add(i,0x1)
                }
            }
            if eq(level,0)
            {
                result := 0x1
            }
            
        }

        let lengthStr := mload(stringNumber) 
        let data := mload(add(stringNumber,0x20))  
        let temp
        
        let  level10 
        for {let i:=0 } 
            lt(i,lengthStr)
            {i := add(i,0x1)}
            {
                temp := sub(data, 0x30) 
                if or(lt(temp,0x0),gt(temp,0x9))
                {
                    res := 0x0
                    stop()
                }
                level10 := power(sub(sub(lengthStr,i),0x1)  ,0xA) //true
                res := add(res, mul(temp,level10))
                data := mload(add(stringNumber,i)))  
            }
       /* try #2
        for {let end := add(data, mul(lengthStr,0x20)) } 
            lt(data,end)
            {data := add(data,0x20)}
            {
                temp := sub(data, 0x30)
                if or(lt(temp,0x0),gt(temp,0x9))
                {
                    res := 0x0
                    stop()
                }
                level10 := power(sub(lengthStr,sub(ind,0x1))  ,0xA)
                res := 1//add(res, mul(temp,level10))
                ind := add(ind,0x1)
            }*/

    }
```

I'm beginner, don't hit me strong, please

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function stringToUint256(string memory _str) internal pure returns(uint256 res) 
{
    bytes memory stringNumber = bytes(_str);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < bytes(_str).length; i++) 
    {
        uint8 codeSymbol = uint8(stringNumber[i]) - 48; 
        if (codeSymbol < 0 || codeSymbol > 9) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        assembly
        {

            let len := mload(stringNumber)
            let level10 := exp(0xA,sub(sub(len,i),1))
            res := add(res, mul(codeSymbol,level10))
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).